# Web AppBuilder Custom Widget - Function Executing Sequence

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-custom-widget

I am having a weired issue that `func1()`, which is coded in front of `func2()`, is executed after `func2()` in my custome widget.

The widget draws a buffer on a click event, and when a "Show Results" button is clicked, it counts the number of facilities within the buffer. Below is a code sample:

```js
var totalFac = 0 // Store the total number of facilities globally
var globalGeometry = null; // Store the query geometry globally

onShowResultsClick: function() {
  totalFac = 0; // Initialize
  this.facLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://link/to/layer");
  var query = new Query();
  query.geometry = globalGeometry;
  this.facLayer.queryFeatures(query, function(result) {
    var features = result.features;
    totalFac = features.length;
    console.log(totalFac);
  });
  console.log(totalFac); // Executed first
},
```

The two `console.log()` functions are executed **reversely**. As `totalFac` is initialized as `0`, the console shows `0` firstly. The the real value of `totalFac` is shown after the `0`. In fact, if `totalFac` is initialized as `888`, the console will show `888` firstly, then the real value. Apparently `queryFeatures()` is executed last, behind the second `console.log()`.

How come that a function coded in front of the next function is executed afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the last console log (the one at the end of `onShowResultsClick`) executes first it that the first console log (the other one) is waiting for the query to be solved.

The `queryFeatures` function do a request to the server to obtain the features. In other words you are telling execute this code (the function you pass as a parameter) when the request is over. It is an asynchronous event, and because of that JavaScript continues executing the code till the request is complete (*)

(*) It is not exactly like this, I simplify to give you the idea. Roughly speaking, there is something call "event loop". Asynchronous events are not executed as soon as they end, instead there are executed in a determined step of the loop.

Comment: Thank you. This makes a lot of sense. How can I force the latter function to wait and run after ```queryFeatures``` is completed?

Comment: You could run the code (for example wrapped in a function), at the end of the function that handles the request success return. In that way it will always execute once the request it is completed successfully. You could also transform the code a bit and use async/await for a similar behavior.